# How to send multiple e-mails with different messages in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, sendmail

I'm trying to send multiple e-mails with different messages.this is my code, it already works and could be sent on 'blazriku@gmail.com' and 'henrikus.antony@gmail.com' but the problem is "send message" and "welcome" always sent to both, not to each other.

then, how to make it "send message" to 'blazriku@gmail.com' and "welcome" to 'henrikus.antony@gmail.com?'

```
    $email = 'blazriku@gmail.com , henrikus.antony@gmail.com';
    $subject = array("send message", "Welcome");
    $message = array("send message", "Welcome");
    $name = array('Admin','Admin');
    $to=$email;


    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: kebunbibit.id <noreply@yourwebsite.com>'."\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: admin@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n"; //untuk cc lebih dari satu tinggal kasih koma
    foreach (array_combine($subject, $message) as $subjects => $messages){
            @mail($to, $subjects, $messages, $headers);

    }
    if(@mail)
    {
    print "<script>window.alert('E-Mail Terkirim!')</script>";  
    print "<script>window.location='home.php?page=surat_jalan'</script>";    
    }
    else{
     print "<script>window.alert('E-Mail Gagal Terkirim!')</script>";  
     print "<script>window.location='home.php?page=surat_jalan'</script>";      
    }
```

Comment: You can't send different messages to different e-mail addresses in the same `mail` call...

Comment: Why don't you wrap your code in a function and then call it twice with different parameters?

Comment: @JonStirling then, could we make other 'mail' function??

Comment: @HenrikusAnthony You can if you want? *shrug*

Comment: @JonStirling but how if I want to make the mail function more than two?

Comment: @zoubida13 Actually I want to make it multiple not just two value. how I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping an email, you may create separate array of emails which are intended for sending different type of subject and emails.and afterwards loop those email array with specified subject and email content.see below:

```
$email = 'blazriku@gmail.com , henrikus.antony@gmail.com';
// $subject = array("send message", "Welcome");
// $message = array("send message", "Welcome");
$name = array('Admin','Admin');
$to=$email;
$welcome_msg_user_group = array('henrikus.antony@gmail.com');
$send_msg_user_group = array('blazriku@gmail.com');

$welcome_email = array('subject' => 'Welcome', 'msg_body' => 'blah blah');
$send_email = array('subject' => 'Send message', 'msg_body' => 'blah blah send msg body');

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: kebunbibit.id <noreply@yourwebsite.com>'."\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: admin@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n"; //untuk cc lebih dari satu tinggal kasih koma    
foreach($welcome_msg_user_group as $welcome_user) {
    @mail($welcome_user, $welcome_email['subject'], $welcome_email['msg_body'], $headers);
}
foreach($send_msg_user_group as $send_user) {
    @mail($send_user, $send_email['subject'], $send_email['msg_body'], $headers);
}

if(@mail)
{
    print "<script>window.alert('E-Mail Terkirim!')</script>";
    print "<script>window.location='home.php?page=surat_jalan'</script>";
}
else {
    print "<script>window.alert('E-Mail Gagal Terkirim!')</script>";
    print "<script>window.location='home.php?page=surat_jalan'</script>";
}
```

Hope it helps you!